# how to show only some URL documentation in django-rest-swagger package

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am using `Django-rest-swagger` Package for documenting my API but I want to show only some URLs to document I have several apps in my project - some answers are USE Exclude but latest version it is not working - 
I am using `djangorestframework==3.5.1` and `Django-rest-swagger==2.1.0` and `Django-rest-framework` for API.

I even tried render-schema and `get_swagger_view(title='API Documentation', patterns=urlpatterns1)`.

but it's not working.

help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Set `exclude_from_schema = True` in your View/Viewset or add it to the decorator (if you use them). This will exclude the view from swagger docs.

django-rest-swagger has changed a lot, in earlier versions there were settings for exclutish urls by name or namespace. Currently you need to exclude the View from the schema drf is generating, it's documented here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view.

Comment: Deprecations
exclude_from_schema is deprecated in DRF 3.7.
Both APIView.exclude_from_schema and the exclude_from_schema argument to the @api_view decorator and now PendingDeprecation. They will be moved to deprecated in the 3.8 release, and removed entirely in 3.9.

For APIView you should instead set a schema = None attribute on the view class. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.7-announcement/